# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de recorrer cada fila en una setencia select en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

Estoy creando un trigger para actualizar el stock de un producto, tengo una tabla que guarda los productos que tiene una promoción, entonces si se vende una promoción debo restar al stock de cada producto que tenga la promoción, entonces para obtener los productos de una promoción hago un `SELECT` pero no se como recorrer cada fila que retorna la sentencia `SELECT`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateProductStock AFTER INSERT ON salesDetail FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE idPromotion INT;
        SET idPromotion = (SELECT product.idPromotion FROM product WHERE id = NEW.idProduct);
        IF idPromotion > 0 THEN
        
            //Aquí necesito recorrer las filas de la sentencia select
            //Mi sentencia select sería:
            //SELECT productsPromotion.idProduct FROM productsPromotion WHERE productsPromotion.idPromotion = idPromotion;
            //La idea es recorrer cada fila que retorna la sentencia select y obtener el idProduct para hacer un update
        
        ELSE
        
            UPDATE product SET product.stock = (product.stock - NEW.quantity) WHERE product.id = NEW.idProduct;
        
        END IF;
    END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Podrías usar un [cursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html), aunque parece que con el `WHERE` del `UPDATE` lo resuelves.

Answer (score 1):

Como dijo @Sal en los comentarios no es necesario en este caso utilizar un bucle o loop, lo puedes hacer con una query.

No me queda muy claro tu modelo de datos a partir de las queries que publicaste en la pregunta. Pareciera que ambas tablas product y productsPromotion tienes columnas idProduct (llamda id en product) e idPromotion.

Para armar la query asumí que un productos puede estar en distintas promociones y una promoción puede tener varios productos, una relación N a N con la tabla productsPromotion (por lo que no podrías guardar la información de la promoción en el producto) y en este caso deberías saber de que promoción se trata (que promoción eligieron); pero como parece que tu guardas el id de la promoción en el producto, no estoy seguro que lo que asumí sea correcto.

En caso de que un producto solo puede estar en una promoción (relación 1 a N) entonces prodías guardar la promoción a la que pertence el producto en la tabla products, y la tabla productsPromotion no sería necesaria en la query (ya que toda la información necesaria estaría en la tabla products).

Con una subquery buscas en productsPromotion los IDs de todos los productos que pertenecen a la misma promoción, luego en la query principal filtras solo aquellos productos que te devolvió la subquery y actualizas el stock (entiendo que descuentas la misma cantidad a cada producto).

```
UPDATE product 
SET product.stock = product.stock - NEW.quantity
WHERE product.id IN (SELECT productsPromotion.idProduct
                    FROM productsPromotion 
                    WHERE productsPromotion.idPromotion = idPromotion);
```